# How to say that any appointment time fits me

Tags: phrase-request

I’m trying to figure out how to say that any appointment time fits me in German.

So I start with usual:

> Ich möchte gerne einen Termin vereinbaren.

And then I know how to specify a time like so:

> Um 11 Uhr wäre mir lieber.

But how do I say that I’m fine with any appointment time?
Is it maybe:

> Alle Uhrzeiten sind gut für mich.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could say:

> Die Uhrzeit kann ich *Ihnen* überlassen.

Or:

> Die Uhrzeit können *Sie* bestimmen.

Or:

> Bei der Uhrzeit kann ich mich nach *Ihnen* richten.
>
> Was die Uhrzeit angeht, kann ich mich nach *Ihnen* richten.

Or:

> Bei der Uhrzeit bin ich flexibel.
>
> Was die Uhrzeit angeht, bin ich flexibel.
>
> Uhrzeit? – Da bin ich flexibel!

Or:

> Uhrzeit? – Wie es Ihnen passt!

Or:

> Ich bin mit jeder Uhrzeit einverstanden.

»Alle Uhrzeiten sind gut für mich« would be unusual, I never heard that.

Comment: 'Die Uhrzeit können Sie bestimmen' finde ich nicht so gut. Ansonsten +1

Answer (score 3):

Wir sind ja nicht an Uhrzeit gebunden.

- Jeder Termin ist mir recht.
- Ich habe keine zeitlichen Präferenzen.
- Ich stehe Ihnen jederzeit zur Verfügung.
- Ich bin zeitlich ungebunden.

Von Pollitzers Vorschlägen gefallen mir aber auch

- Die Uhrzeit können Sie bestimmen.
- Bei der Uhrzeit kann ich mich nach Ihnen richten.

gut.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answers wouldn't fit to your question that much, but they could be helpful anyway!

In some situation you might be asked for an appointment time and instead answering you may ask (this option is quoted by Pollitizer):

> Wann passt es Ihnen (denn)?
>
> Wann würde es Ihnen (denn) passen?
>
> Wann haben Sie Zeit? ...

or

> Wie passt es Ihnen denn?

Sometimes you may have the possibility to switch tasks or have more or less free time and want to check if the time that fits the person you'd like or need to meet fits your need too, so you may say:

> Machen Sie, bitte (rather polite option)/doch ein Vorschlag?

In the same situation you could also use:

> Ich bin (zeitlich) flexibel.
>
> Ich kann mich (zeitlich) auf Sie einstellen.

These are similar sayings to "zeitlich ungebunden" (quoted by user unknown)

Or you could say:

> Wann immer Sie möchten.

or

> Wie es Ihnen passt. (also quoted by Pollitizer)

Note that the last two may also, say that you'll have nothing to do or no plans at all, but also show that you are interested in the appointment, so if you are meeting for business it might have some negative touch.